Where can I install the XR_FB_passthrough OpenXR extension in UE 4.27
I'm assuming it's part of the Oculus OpenXR plugin but I can't find any reference in there to passthrough.
Even with that plugin xrCreatePassthroughFB isn't implemented, I've tried looking at different versions of the Meta OpenXR SDK but can't find where xrCreatePassthroughFB is defined, the prototypes are all defined in the core openxr.h when enabling them, but the implementations won't be linked.
I assume there will be a header that defines those functions without being locked behind XR_EXTENSION_PROTOTYPES definition.
I tried looking through the Oculus/Meta OpenXR SDK but haven't found anything useful.
